# Adding class attributes to a form prevents 'hasdatepicker' inheritance

Tags: forms, 8

I have a form to which I’ve added an input element of type ‘date’.  When I add a attribute-class property the date-picker behavior stops working. This is the code for the element:

```
$form['stop_date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('Stop Date'),
  '#default_value' => date("Y-m-d"),
  '#id' => 'stop_date', 
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('dateSel-Fld')), // ADD CLASS TO FORM ELEMENT
  '#required' => true,
);
```

This is the HTML output:

```
<input id="stop_date" class="dateSel-Fld form-date required" 
type="date" aria-required="true" required="required" 
value="2016-03-11" name="stop_date" data-drupal-selector="stop-date">
```

When I remove #attribute, the HTML is the following:

```
<input id="stop_date" class="form-date required hasDatepicker" 
type="date" aria-required="true" required="required" 
value="2016-03-11" name="stop_date" data-drupal-date-format="Y-m-d" 
data-drupal-selector="stop-date">
```

So, adding the attribute property prevents the default behavior of adding the 'datepicker' class to the element.

What am I doing wrong?

NewProtocol.php:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements an example form.
 */
class NewProtocol extends FormBase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId()
    {
        return 'NewProtocol_Form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'GenoForm/GenoForm'; // attach css and js libs  

        $form['stop_date'] = array(
          '#type' => 'date',
          '#title' => t('Stop Date'),
          '#default_value' => date("Y-m-d"), // default to today 
          '#id' => 'stop_date', // ADD ID TO FORM ELEMENT
          '#attributes' => array('class' => array('dateSel-Fld')), // ADD CLASS TO FORM ELEMENT
          '#required' => true,
        );
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $a = 1;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $a = 1;
    }
}
```

GenoForm.js:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains js for the GenoForm module.
 */

// attaches a keyup funcion to form element by id
// - needed to alter value in $form_state[values]
//(function($) {
//    $(function() {
//        $('#genotype_3_id').keyup(function() {
//            this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
//        });
//    })
//})(jQuery);
```

GenoForm.css:

```
/* 
    Created on : Feb 27, 2016, 2:19:35 PM
    Author     : michael.sullivan
*/
.dateSel-Fld {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

GenoForm.libraries.yml

```
GenoForm:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/GenoForm.css: {}

  js:
    js/GenoForm.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Comment: You want to add jQuery UI datepicker behavior(because hasDatepicker it is it's class)? If yes, please inform us how did you add support of jQuery UI datepicker to your field.

Comment: I did it using a yml library file that adds     - core/jquery as a dependency    js:
    js/GenoForm.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery

Comment: Please give full code example of how you attach libraries and what you have in GenoForm.js(as I understand it's your own js-file).

Comment: I've added all the files involved in the behavior.  As you can see the behavior is not affected by the GenoForm.js as all code in there is commented out.  Thanks for your help in this.

Comment: I found the php log has this message: Undefined index: type in Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Date::processDate() 
(line 69 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/D8-3-Mouse/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/Date.php)

Comment: There is a discussion of this at: https://www.drupal.org/node/2528482   but the discussion is over 7 months old and I would have the version of drupal I'm using would have had this bug fixed.